# bulkwrite does not support multi-document transaction by using mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, mongo-go

I's using mongo-go-driver 0.0.18 to build a bulk write which is consisted of a "NewUpdateManyModel" and several "NewInsertOneModel". My mongo server is atlas M10 with replica sets. I built some goroutines to test if the transactions are atomic, the result shows that each bulk write is not atomic, they would interfered with each other. I am wondering if mongo-go-driver supports for multi-document transaction?

```
func insertUpdateQuery(counter int, col *mongo.Collection, group *sync.WaitGroup){
var operations []mongo.WriteModel
var items = []item{}
items=append(items,item{"Name":strconv.Itoa(counter),"Description":"latest one"})

for _,v := range items{
    operations = append(operations, mongo.NewInsertOneModel().Document(v))
}

updateOperation := mongo.NewUpdateManyModel()
updateOperation.Filter(bson.D{
    {"Name", bson.D{
        {"$ne", strconv.Itoa(counter)},
    }},
})
updateOperation.Update(bson.D{
    {"$set", bson.D{
        {"Description", strconv.Itoa(counter)},
    }},
},)
operations = append(operations,updateOperation)

bulkOps:=options.BulkWrite()
result, err := col.BulkWrite(
    context.Background(),
    operations,
    bulkOps,
)
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println("err:",err)
}else{
    fmt.Printf("IU: %+v \n",result)
}

group.Done()

}


func retrieveQuery(group *sync.WaitGroup, col *mongo.Collection){
var results []item
qctx:=context.Background()
qctx, c := context.WithTimeout(qctx, 10*time.Second)
defer c()
cur, err := col.Find(qctx, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer cur.Close(context.Background())
res := item{}
for cur.Next(context.Background()) {
    err := cur.Decode(&res)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }else {
        results=append(results,res)
    }
}
if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println("res:",results)

group.Done()
}



func main()  {
ctx := context.Background()
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx,10*time.Second)
defer cancel()

uri := "..."
client, err := mongo.NewClient(uri)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("todo: couldn't connect to mongo: %v", err)
}
defer cancel()
err = client.Connect(ctx)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("todo: mongo client couldn't connect with background context: %v", err)
}
col:=client.Database("jistest").Collection("Rules")

wg :=&sync.WaitGroup{}

for i:=0; i<100; i++{
    wg.Add(2)
    go insertUpdateQuery(i,col,wg)
    go retrieveQuery(wg,col)

}
wg.Wait()
fmt.Println("All Done!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if mongo-go-driver supports for multi-document transaction?

[mongo-go-driver](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) does support multi-document transaction since [v0.0.12](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-286) (currently in beta version 0.1.0).

[MongoDB multi-document transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions) are associated with a session. That is, you start a transaction for a session. When using any of MongoDB officially supported drivers, you must pass the [session](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Session/) to each operation in the transaction.

Your example does not seem to utilise session nor transactions. An example of multi-document transaction in mongo-go-driver (v0.1.0) is as below:

```
client, err := mongo.NewClient("<MONGODB URI>")
if err != nil { return err }
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
defer cancel()
err = client.Connect(ctx)
if err != nil { return err }

session, err := client.StartSession()
database := client.Database("databaseName")
collection := database.Collection("collectionName")

err = mongo.WithSession(ctx, session, func(sctx mongo.SessionContext) error {
        // Start a transaction in the session 
        sctx.StartTransaction()

        var operations []mongo.WriteModel
        // Create an insert one operation
        operations = append(operations,
                            mongo.NewInsertOneModel().Document(
                            bson.D{{"Name", counter}, 
                                   {"Description", "latest"}}))

        // Create an update many operation
        updateOperation := mongo.NewUpdateManyModel()
        updateOperation.Filter(bson.D{{"Name", bson.D{
            {"$ne", counter},
        }}})
        updateOperation.Update(bson.D{
            {"$set", bson.D{
                {"Description", counter},
            }},
        })
        operations = append(operations, updateOperation)

        // Execute bulkWrite operation in a transactional session.
        _, err := collection.BulkWrite(sctx, operations)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        }
        // Committing transaction
        session.CommitTransaction(sctx)
        return nil
})
session.EndSession(ctx)
```

See also [Transactions and Retryable Writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-and-retryable-writes) for examples to retry transactions.

> I built some goroutines to test if the transactions are atomic

Just be mindful about how the processes are executed. For example, depending on the racing condition, you may get the latest performance overwriting the result. i.e.

```
transaction 1 finished 
transaction 2 finished 
transaction 3 and transaction 4 conflict 
transaction 5 finished
...
```