# mongodb can't do transaction in Go and always got Cannot create namespace in multi-document transaction

Tags: mongodb, go, transactions

I am trying to create a function that InsertOne data by wrap transaction, and I already to replica set in mongodb also, I tried in local and and MongoDB atlas the error were same,
here is the code:

```
    const MONGODB_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/?replicaSet=rs"
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(MONGODB_URI))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db := client.Database("production")
    defer db.Client().Disconnect(ctx)
    col := db.Collection("people")

    // transaction
    err = db.Client().UseSession(ctx, func(sessionContext mongo.SessionContext) error {
        err := sessionContext.StartTransaction()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        }

        _, err = col.InsertOne(sessionContext, req)
        if err != nil {
            sessionContext.AbortTransaction(sessionContext)
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        } else {
            sessionContext.CommitTransaction(sessionContext)
        }
        return nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

I have follow the instructions of [this question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54398579/12174355) and I have tried also ways from [this article mongodb developer](https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/golang-multi-document-acid-transactions)

what I got is this error:

```
(NamespaceNotFound) Cannot create namespace 
production.people in multi-document transaction.
```

and

```
multiple write errors: [{write errors: 
[{Cannot create namespace spura.people in multi-document transaction.}]},
 {<nil>}]"
```

it got error when I inserted data , is that something wrong in my code? I have tried look carefully and try the instruction of document or articles and always got that error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB 4.2 and lower [does not permit creating collections in transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#operations). This restriction is lifted in 4.4.

For 4.2 and lower, [create the collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) ahead of time.

Comment: did u meant I should create collection into the mongo by manually and run that syntax ??

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.